# опция -MP и -MMD компилятора gcc

Tags: gcc, g++, компилятор, makefile

Где можно почитать про эти опции, не могу найти информации(-MP и -MMD).
[image: Требования к работе]

Comment: в документации к gcc? ps эти опции малополезны, как и make файлы в целом

Comment: Тут: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-9.3.0/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#Preprocessor-Options